# Extjs delete record using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, extjs, extjs4

Okay, so I am following this tutorial: http://existdissolve.com/2013/05/extjs-4-2-walkthrough-part-4-steppin-in-some-crud/

I am using Codeigniter as the backend and following the ExtJs from the tutorial.

Here is my color controller:

```
/**
 * Generic controller for managing simple options
 */
Ext.define('CarTracker.controller.Options', {
extend: 'CarTracker.controller.Base',
stores: [
    'option.Colors'
],
views: [
    'option.List'
],
refs: [
    {
        ref: 'OptionList',
        selector: '[xtype=option.list]'
    }
],
init: function() {
    this.listen({
        component: {
            'grid[xtype=option.list]': {
                edit: this.save,
                canceledit: this.cancel,
                beforerender: this.loadRecords,
                itemcontextmenu: this.showContextMenu
            },
            'grid[xtype=option.list] button#add': {
                click: this.add
            },
            'grid[xtype=option.list] gridview': {
                itemadd: this.edit
            }
        }
    });
},
/**
 * Displays context menu 
 * @param {Ext.view.View} view
 * @param {Ext.data.Model} record 
 * @param {HTMLElement} item
 * @param {Number} index
 * @param {Ext.EventObject} e
 * @param {Object} eOpts
 */
showContextMenu: function( view, record, item, index, e, eOpts ) {
    var me = this;
    // stop event so browser's normal right-click action doesn't continue
    e.stopEvent();
    // if a menu doesn't already exist, create one
    if( !item.contextMenu ) {
        // add menu
        item.contextMenu = new Ext.menu.Menu({
            items: [
                {
                    text: 'Edit Item',
                    iconCls: 'icon_edit',
                    handler: function( item, e ) {
                        var grid = me.getOptionList(),
                            plugin = grid.editingPlugin;
                        // start row edit
                        plugin.startEdit( record, 0 );
                    }
                },
                {
                    text: 'Delete Item',
                    iconCls: 'icon_delete',
                    handler: function( item, e ) {
                        me.remove( record );
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
    }
    // show menu relative to item which was right-clicked
    item.contextMenu.showBy( item );
},
/**
 * Loads the grid's store
 * @param {Ext.grid.Panel}
 * @param {Object}
 */
loadRecords: function( grid, eOpts ) {
    var me = this,
        store = grid.getStore();
    // clear any fliters that have been applied
    store.clearFilter( true );
    // load the store
    store.load();
},
/**
 * Cancels the edit of a record
 * @param {Ext.grid.plugin.Editing} editor
 * @param {Object} context
 * @param {Object} eOpts
 */
cancel: function( editor, context, eOpts ) {
    // if the record is a phantom, remove from store and grid
    if( context.record.phantom ) {
        context.store.remove( context.record );
    }
},
/**
 * Begins edit of selected record
 * @param {Ext.data.Model[]} records
 * @param {Number} index
 * @param {Object} node
 * @param {Object} eOpts
 */
edit: function( records, index, node, eOpts ) {
    var me = this,
        grid = me.getOptionList(),
        plugin = grid.editingPlugin;
    // start edit of row
    plugin.startEdit( records[ 0 ], 0 );
},
/**
 * Creates a new record and prepares it for editing
 * @param {Ext.button.Button} button
 * @param {Ext.EventObject} e
 * @param {Object} eOpts
 */
add: function( button, e, eOpts ) {
    var me = this,
        grid = me.getOptionList(),
        plugin = grid.editingPlugin,
        store = grid.getStore();
    // if we're already editing, don't allow new record insert
    if( plugin.editing ) {
        // show error message
        Ext.Msg.alert( 'Attention', 'Please finish editing before inserting a new record' );
        return false;
    }
    store.insert( 0, {} );
},
/**
 * Displays context menu 
 * @param {Ext.grid.plugin.Editing} editor
 * @param {Object} context
 * @param {Object} eOpts
 */
save: function( editor, context, eOpts ) {
    var me = this,
        store = context.record.store;
    // save
    store.save();
},
/**
 * Displays context menu 
 * @param {Ext.data.Model[]} record
 */
remove: function( record ) {
    var me = this,
        store = record.store;
    // show confirmation before continuing
    Ext.Msg.confirm( 'Attention', 'Are you sure you want to delete this item? This action cannot be undone.', function( buttonId, text, opt ) {
        if( buttonId=='yes' ) {
            console.log(record);
            store.destroy( record );
            store.sync({
                /**
                 * On failure, add record back to store at correct index
                 * @param {Ext.data.Model[]} records
                 * @param {Ext.data.Operation} operation
                 */
                failure: function( records, operation ) {
                    store.rejectChanges();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
});
```

Here is my color model:

```
Ext.define('CarTracker.model.option.Color', {
extend: 'CarTracker.model.option.Base',
fields: [
   // id field
   {
       name: 'id',
       type: 'int',
       useNull : true
   }
] 
});
```

Here is my color store

```
/**
 * Store for managing car colors
 */
Ext.define('CarTracker.store.option.Colors', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
alias: 'store.option.color',
requires: [
    'CarTracker.model.option.Color'
],
storeId: 'Colors',
model: 'CarTracker.model.option.Color',
remoteFilter: true,
remoteSort: true,
proxy: {
    type: 'rest',
    actionMethods: {
        create: 'POST',
        read: 'GET',
        update: 'POST',
        destroy: 'POST'
    },
    api: {
        create: 'index.php/color/create',
        read: 'index.php/color/read',
        update: 'index.php/color/update',
        destroy: 'index.php/color/delete'
    },
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'data',
        totalProperty: 'count'
    },
    writer: {
        type: 'json',
        writeAllFields: false,
        allowSingle: false,
        encode: true,
        root: 'data'
    }
}
});
```

On the backend I have a simple-as-can-be controller and model that doesnt do ANYTHING special but delete the record of the ID sent in. However, the id sent in always looks something like this:

```
CarTracker.model.option.Color-6
```

For the life of me I can't figure out why I am getting THIS as the ID instead of simply '6'. I am fairly new to extjs and the structure he is using in the tutorial is a bit different from what I have seen elsewhere.

Here is the request:

```
Request URL:http://localhost/cartracker/index.php/color/delete/CarTracker.model.option.Color-6?_dc=1380747404785
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:46
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Host:localhost
Origin:http://localhost
Referer:http://localhost/cartracker/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)         Chrome/29.0.1547.76 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Query String Parametersview sourceview URL encoded
_dc:1380747404785
Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
id:CarTracker.model.option.Color-6
data:[]
Response Headersview source
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:387
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Wed, 02 Oct 2013 20:56:44 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Server:Apache/2.4.4 (Win32) OpenSSL/0.9.8y PHP/5.4.19
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.4.19
```

Comment: Can you post the whole request body

Answer (score 0):

So here is the thing. When I first started trying to "fix" the code I changed store.remove() in my controller to store.remove(). That seemed to be working better at first. (Im new to extjs and im still not 100% sure what the difference is). Then farther down the line I determined to change my id to 'id' instead of 'ColorId' thus needing to change my idProperty in my model. However, because of my first change I was not getting the id (maybe destroy doesn't send one...or it does but only certain conditions? No clue).

Solution: I changed store.destroy() BACK to store.remove() in the controller and then set the idProperty in my model to 'id'. I am now getting the proper ID.